# Simple Calculator Knockout

Tags: knockout.js

I want to make a simple calculator. My problem is in the addition function, when I enter the value it does not add the two value but instead concatenate those two value. Can someone help me fix this. Here are my coding:

```
var Calculator = function (number,addNum) {
 var self = this;
 self.number = ko.observable(number);
 self.addNum = ko.observable (addNum);

 self.sum = ko.computed(function(){
    return self.number() + self.addNum();
  });   
}
ko.applyBindings(new Calculator());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because they're bound to input boxes, `self.number()` and `self.addNum()` are strings (even if they are originally numbers). Use `parseFloat()`...

```
 self.sum = ko.computed(function(){
    return parseFloat(self.number()) + parseFloat(self.addNum());
  });
```

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/y1tjg4qt/)